# remove .pdb from the end of a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string which can be any name followed by `.pdb`or `PDB`. Is there anyway can I remove the `pdb` or `PDB` in the same line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what you tried to solve your problem, I can only give you some **hints** :

You should take a look to :

- the [replace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method
- the [os.path.splitext()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path#os.path.splitext) method

Answer (score 1):

Another way that could provide more flexibility is to use a regular expression substitution, e.g:

```
re.sub(r'\.(pdb|PDB)',
       r'',
       filename);
```

Or alternatively the `(?i)` syntax makes the whole regular expression case-insensitive:

```
re.sub(r'(?i)\.pdb',
       r'',
       filename);
```